# lateinit property viewModelFactory has not been initialized in Fragment

Tags: android, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

I am using dagger 2 (version 2.15) for dependency injection in my android project.
Everything works fine except injecting viewModelFactory.
I cannot inject it in my fragment.

```
@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

private val mainViewModel: StationsViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(StationsViewModel::class.java)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
lateinit property viewModelFactory has not been initialized
```

I have ViewModelModule:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(MainViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun bindsMainViewModel(mainViewModel: 
    MainViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: MyViewModelFactory): 
    ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

ViewModelKey

```
@MustBeDocumented
@Target(
        AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

and ViewModelFactory

```
@Singleton
class MyViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
        private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }
}
```

although I do not quite understand what they are doing.

Comment: It was because I forgot to extend DaggerFragment

Comment: Gotta call `AndroidSupportInjection` but there is a way to automatize it based on the GithubBrowserSample if you register a lifecycle listener see Application

Answer (score 5):

Can you try to initiate in onViewCreated() ?

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
        .get(StationsViewModel::class.java)
    // binding.viewmodel = viewModel
}
```

Should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just forgot initialize ViewModelModule like next

```
@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class AppModule(private val appContext: Context) 
// .....some code here
}
```

as ViewModelModule provides the MyViewModelFactory instance